# What does it mean to weigh the columns of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, terminology

What does it mean to weigh the columns of a matrix?

> [image]

What does it mean in this context specifically? Can someone please give me an example in general or with respect to a character table?

Comment: To "weight" them, not "weigh" them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Weighting" a column in this context just means multiplying it by a constant.

For instance, the character table of $S_4$ is given by
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\text{classes:} & 1 & (1\,2) & (1\,2\,3) & (1\,2\,3\,4) & (1\,2)(3\,4)\\
\text{sizes:} & 1&6&8&6&3\\
\hline
\chi_1 & 1&1&1&1&1\\
\chi_2 & 1&-1&1&-1&1\\
\chi_3 & 2&0&-1&0&2\\
\chi_4 & 3&1&0&-1&-1\\
\chi_5 & 3&-1&0&1&1
\end{array}
$$
The columns of this table are indeed orthogonal, but they are not of unit length.  In order to make the table into a unitary matrix, we need to **weight** the columns, i.e. multiply each column by a number.  That is, we need to normalize the columns.

So, if we look at the third column for instance, we have to divide the column by $\|(1,1,-1,0,0)\| = \sqrt{3}$ in order to make it a unit-vector.  As noted in the excerpt you link, the squared norm of the column is $3$, which is also equal to the size of the group, $|G| = 4! = 24$, divided by the size of the conjugacy class, $8$.

For a more dramatic example: the squared norm of the first column is 
$$
1^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 3^2 = 24
$$
which is equal to $24$ (the size of the group) divided by $1$ (the size of the conjugacy class).